# Using a second thermostat as a remote temp sensor

Tags: thermostat

I’m using Honeywell WiFi enabled  thermostats to control heating and cooling at home and cottage. I would like to add another thermostat of the same type simply so that I can remotely read the temperature in the basement of the cottage, not to control the furnace.  Should I be able to simply attach ground and C wires to that 2nd thermostat?

Thx ... Dave.

Comment: What model is your thermostat? Many of the fancier Honeywells can use a remote temp sensor accessory....

Comment: "ground" and "C" are the same wire ...

Comment: There are WiFi thermostats like the Ecobee and Nest that support remote temperature sensors.  I have an Ecobee with a remote sensor in each bedroom and it works great.  The sensors last a year using a coin-cell battery.

Answer (score 1):

No, the stat needs 24vac for the wifi, which is supplied by the furnace from the R and C terminals. You can easily find on Amazon or other retail sites a "24vac C wire adapter" and you can install the thermostat anywhere near a 120v receptacle.

Comment: Thermostats are 2xRTH6580WF and one RTH9585WF in one house (three separate units) and RTH6580WF at the cottage.  It's at the cottage that I want to be able to read the basement temperature when we're away.  I hadn't used my meter on the wires and assumed that C was power, since there was a ground as well (I think).  So I could simply use a 24vac transformer and not attach to the furnace at all ?  That would be a better solution and ensure that no one could screw around with the settings on that basement thermostat to conflict with the other.

Comment: Interesting.  Yes, I disconnected all wires other than the C & R from an existing thermostat and read the voltage - 27 - and plugged in the thermostat and sure enough it was then operating as a wifi remote sensor.  I guess that I'll go ahead and purchase the other thermostat to install at the cottage when we're up there at Christmas.  Thanks for the assist.  Dave.